# Finitely generated submonoids of commutative cancellative gcd monoids

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, gcd-and-lcm, monoid, finitely-generated

Let $(M,\cdot,1)$ be a commutative cancellative gcd monoid. That is,

- $\forall a,b\in M\colon a\cdot b =b\cdot a$
- $\forall a,b,c\in M\colon (c\cdot a = c\cdot b)\implies (a=b)$
- $\forall a,b\in M\colon \gcd(a,b)\neq\emptyset$

Let $\Gamma=\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ be a finite subset of $M$. Surely, $\langle\Gamma\rangle_\cdot$ is commutative and cancellative, but not necessarily gcd-closed.

**Does there exist a finitely generated gcd monoid $M'$ such that $\langle\Gamma\rangle_\cdot\le M'\le M$?**

I have now crawled all of the related literature I could find on the internet and still have no clear answer. Unfortunately, I am not a frequent in this theory and can only judge from the precisely formulated statements I can find in the literature.

It seems that if $M'$ existed, it would be a unique factorization monoid, since it would be generated by primes and units (as it is gcd). My gut tells me that this is unlikely to be the case.

Comment: What are your definitions of a gcd-monoid and of a gcd-closed submonid?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Given $a,b\in M$ the set of greatest common divisors is denoted by $\gcd(a,b)$. I call $M$ gcd-monoid if $\forall a,b\in M\colon \gcd(a,b)\neq\emptyset$. Given a submonoid $M'\le M$, I call $M'$ gcd-closed (in $M$) if $\forall a,b\in M\colon \gcd(a,b)\cap M'\neq \emptyset$.
$\\$
I wish to note here that with my statement "$\langle\Gamma\rangle_\cdot$ is [..] not necessarily gcd-closed" I did not want to express desire for $\langle\Gamma\rangle_\cdot$ to be gcd-closed. I would be happy if there existed $M'$ (with possibly different gcds than the ones from $M$).

Comment: Thanks. It would be a good idea to include these definitions in your question.